# Bluetooth mouse connection takes about 20+ seconds to resolve on wake up on KDE Neon (Ubuntu) - why?

Tags: ubuntu, usb, mouse, bluetooth, wireless-mouse

Can anybody help to clarify why the bluetooth resolution for simple bluetooth mouse would take about 20-30 seconds to usable?

This is the bluetooth log:

```
$ bluetoothctl
Agent registered
[CHG] Device B4:BC:7C:2F:CF:A5 Connected: yes
[400-MA102]# list
Controller E0:D4:E8:11:50:52 x [default]
[CHG] Device B4:BC:7C:2F:CF:A5 ServicesResolved: yes
[CHG] Device B4:BC:7C:2F:CF:A5 Paired: yes
[CHG] Device B4:BC:7C:2F:CF:A5 ServicesResolved: no
[CHG] Device B4:BC:7C:2F:CF:A5 Connected: no
[CHG] Device B4:BC:7C:2F:CF:A5 Connected: yes
[NEW] Primary Service (Handle 0x0000)
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_B4_BC_7C_2F_CF_A5/service000c
00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
Generic Attribute Profile
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x0000)
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_B4_BC_7C_2F_CF_A5/service000c/char000d
00002a05-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
Service Changed
[NEW] Descriptor (Handle 0x0000)
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_B4_BC_7C_2F_CF_A5/service000c/char000d/desc000f
00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
Client Characteristic Configuration
[NEW] Primary Service (Handle 0x0000)
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_B4_BC_7C_2F_CF_A5/service0010
0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
Device Information
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x0000)
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_B4_BC_7C_2F_CF_A5/service0010/char0011
00002a23-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
System ID
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x0000)
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_B4_BC_7C_2F_CF_A5/service0010/char0013
00002a24-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
Model Number String
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x0000)
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_B4_BC_7C_2F_CF_A5/service0010/char0015
00002a25-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
Serial Number String
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x0000)
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_B4_BC_7C_2F_CF_A5/service0010/char0017
00002a26-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
Firmware Revision String
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x0000)
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_B4_BC_7C_2F_CF_A5/service0010/char0019
00002a27-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
Hardware Revision String
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x0000)
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_B4_BC_7C_2F_CF_A5/service0010/char001b
00002a28-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
Software Revision String
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x0000)
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_B4_BC_7C_2F_CF_A5/service0010/char001d
00002a29-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
Manufacturer Name String
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x0000)
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_B4_BC_7C_2F_CF_A5/service0010/char001f
00002a2a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
IEEE 11073-20601 Regulatory Cert. Data List
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x0000)
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_B4_BC_7C_2F_CF_A5/service0010/char0021
00002a50-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
PnP ID
[NEW] Primary Service (Handle 0x0000)
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_B4_BC_7C_2F_CF_A5/service0023
0000180f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
Battery Service
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x0000)
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_B4_BC_7C_2F_CF_A5/service0023/char0024
00002a19-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
Battery Level
[NEW] Descriptor (Handle 0x0000)
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_B4_BC_7C_2F_CF_A5/service0023/char0024/desc0026
00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
Client Characteristic Configuration
[NEW] Descriptor (Handle 0x0000)
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_B4_BC_7C_2F_CF_A5/service0023/char0024/desc0027
00002908-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
Report Reference
[NEW] Descriptor (Handle 0x0000)
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_B4_BC_7C_2F_CF_A5/service0023/char0024/desc0028
00002904-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
Characteristic Format
[CHG] Device B4:BC:7C:2F:CF:A5 ServicesResolved: yes
```

/etc/bluetooth/input.conf:

```
# Configuration file for the input service

# This section contains options which are not specific to any
# particular interface
[General]

# Set idle timeout (in minutes) before the connection will
# be disconnect (defaults to 0 for no timeout)
IdleTimeout=0

# Enable HID protocol handling in userspace input profile
# Defaults to false (HIDP handled in HIDP kernel module)
UserspaceHID=false

# Limit HID connections to bonded devices
# The HID Profile does not specify that devices must be bonded, however some
# platforms may want to make sure that input connections only come from bonded
# device connections. Several older mice have been known for not supporting
# pairing/encryption.
# Defaults to false to maximize device compatibility.
#ClassicBondedOnly=true

# LE upgrade security
# Enables upgrades of security automatically if required.
# Defaults to true to maximize device compatibility.
#LEAutoSecurity=true
```

/etc/bluetooth/main.conf:

```
[General]

# Default adaper name
# Defaults to 'BlueZ X.YZ'
#Name = BlueZ

# Default device class. Only the major and minor device class bits are
# considered. Defaults to '0x000000'.
#Class = 0x000100

# How long to stay in discoverable mode before going back to non-discoverable
# The value is in seconds. Default is 180, i.e. 3 minutes.
# 0 = disable timer, i.e. stay discoverable forever
#DiscoverableTimeout = 0

# How long to stay in pairable mode before going back to non-discoverable
# The value is in seconds. Default is 0.
# 0 = disable timer, i.e. stay pairable forever
#PairableTimeout = 0

# Automatic connection for bonded devices driven by platform/user events.
# If a platform plugin uses this mechanism, automatic connections will be
# enabled during the interval defined below. Initially, this feature
# intends to be used to establish connections to ATT channels. Default is 60.
#AutoConnectTimeout = 60

# Use vendor id source (assigner), vendor, product and version information for
# DID profile support. The values are separated by ":" and assigner, VID, PID
# and version.
# Possible vendor id source values: bluetooth, usb (defaults to usb)
#DeviceID = bluetooth:1234:5678:abcd

# Do reverse service discovery for previously unknown devices that connect to
# us. This option is really only needed for qualification since the BITE tester
# doesn't like us doing reverse SDP for some test cases (though there could in
# theory be other useful purposes for this too). Defaults to 'true'.
#ReverseServiceDiscovery = true

# Enable name resolving after inquiry. Set it to 'false' if you don't need
# remote devices name and want shorter discovery cycle. Defaults to 'true'.
#NameResolving = true

# Enable runtime persistency of debug link keys. Default is false which
# makes debug link keys valid only for the duration of the connection
# that they were created for.
#DebugKeys = false

# Restricts all controllers to the specified transport. Default value
# is "dual", i.e. both BR/EDR and LE enabled (when supported by the HW).
# Possible values: "dual", "bredr", "le"
#ControllerMode = dual

# Enables Multi Profile Specification support. This allows to specify if
# system supports only Multiple Profiles Single Device (MPSD) configuration
# or both Multiple Profiles Single Device (MPSD) and Multiple Profiles Multiple
# Devices (MPMD) configurations.
# Possible values: "off", "single", "multiple"
#MultiProfile = off

# Permanently enables the Fast Connectable setting for adapters that
# support it. When enabled other devices can connect faster to us,
# however the tradeoff is increased power consumptions. This feature
# will fully work only on kernel version 4.1 and newer. Defaults to
# 'false'.
FastConnectable = true

[Policy]

# The ReconnectUUIDs defines the set of remote services that should try
# to be reconnected to in case of a link loss (link supervision
# timeout). The policy plugin should contain a sane set of values by
# default, but this list can be overridden here. By setting the list to
# empty the reconnection feature gets disabled.
#ReconnectUUIDs=00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb, 0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb

# ReconnectAttempts define the number of attempts to reconnect after a link
# lost. Setting the value to 0 disables reconnecting feature.
ReconnectAttempts=10

# ReconnectIntervals define the set of intervals in seconds to use in between
# attempts.
# If the number of attempts defined in ReconnectAttempts is bigger than the
# set of intervals the last interval is repeated until the last attempt.
ReconnectIntervals=1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64

# AutoEnable defines option to enable all controllers when they are found.
# This includes adapters present on start as well as adapters that are plugged
# in later on. Defaults to 'false'.
AutoEnable=true
```

As you can see I have tried to change default main.conf settings to faster reconnect intervals and even trying to specify ReconnectUUIDs (now commented out), but to no avail.

Bluetooth in KDE Neon system tray is showing as connected immediately after wake up, but mouse is unusable (won't move cursor).

Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: Just for reference: Sometimes my Bluetooth mouse at work takes 30+ seconds to (re-)connect to my Windows notebook when resuming from hibernation. Not always though!

Comment: I use a LogiTech BT Mouse and it works fine in Windows, Ubuntu and Kali.   Make sure the BT drivers are up to date. That is a good starting point.

Comment: Test also with another Bluetooth mouse.

Comment: Another mouse (to Harry's point) will likely have newer drivers.   You may be losing pairing (earlier or incompatible drivers)

Comment: Still no luck. I have tried different configs, only `service bluetooth restart` works to force mouse working immediately.